# copy cells in a range to a column

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

i have MyRange = A1:C3

current values in the range are as below:

A1=a, B1=d, C1=f
A2=b, B2=e, C2=""
A3=c, B3="", C3=""

the blank cells in the range can vary.

how can i copy (using vba) non-blank values from MyRange and paste them all together let's say to column AA?

Eg:
AA1=a
AA2=b
AA3=c
AA4=d
AA5=e
AA6=f

Thanks again guys :-)
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all cells in MyRange, if cell is not "" copy value to next target cell

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyRange as Range
    Dim TargetCell as Range
    Dim rw as Range
    Dime cl as Range

    Set MyRange = ActiveWorkbook.Names("MyRange").RefersToRange
    Set TargetCell = Range("AA1") 
    For each rw in MyRange.Columns
        For each cl in rw.Cells
            If cl.value <> "" then
                TargetCell = cl.value
                Set TargetCell = TargetCell.Offset(1,0)
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: hi chris, can you put the full coding that goes with your answer... i can't get it to work. this is what i did: 

`code` 
Public Sub test()

Set targetcell = Range("AA1")
For Each rw In Range("MyRange").Columns
    For Each cl In rw.Cells
        If cl.Value <> "" Then
            targetcell = cl.Value
            Set targetcell = targetcell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
`code` 

and i get "Run-time error '424: Object required"

even if i add 

`code`
Dim rw As String
Dim cl As String
`code`

i get the same error...

thank you
paul

Comment: hi chris, can you put the full coding that goes with your answer... i can't get it to work. this is what i did: 

` 
Public Sub test()

Set targetcell = Range("AA1")
For Each rw In Range("MyRange").Columns
    For Each cl In rw.Cells
        If cl.Value <> "" Then
            targetcell = cl.Value
            Set targetcell = targetcell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
` 

and i get "Run-time error '424: Object required"

even if i add 

`
Dim rw As String
Dim cl As String
`

i get the same error...

thank you or anyone!

paul

Comment: Also formatting, returns, code marks don't work on my posts... what am i doing wrong? ta

Comment: @paul when you say 'i have MyRange = A1:C3' do you mean you have a variable called MyRange set to the range A1:C1? I'll edited to a more complete sub.